# SQL - How to query a VIEW with a CASE expression - Find the average number in a column

Tags: sql, sql-view

I am looking to compute the avg win odds and avg place odds of horse racing markets

I have tried a `CASE` expression since averages for WinOdds should only be calculated if `Place =1` and averages for PlaceOdds should only be included when `Place <= 10`

```
SELECT 

  CASE WHEN Place = 1 THEN AVG(IndustrySP) AS AvgWinOdds,
  CASE WHEN Place <= 10 THEN AVG((IndustrySP - 1.0) / 5) AS AvgPlaceOdds

FROM dbo.GrandNational -- This is the `view` I want to query
```

I am looking for average odds for win (when Place =1)

and average odds for place (when Place is <= 10)

Should return something like this:

```
-- AvgWinOdds   -- AvgPlaceOdds

-- 6.44         -- 4.22
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! ([mcve])

Comment: Is that table data, the current result or the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must average the CASE expressions:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Place = 1 THEN IndustrySP END) AS AvgWinOdds,
  AVG(CASE WHEN Place <= 10 THEN (IndustrySP - 1.0) / 5 END) AS AvgPlaceOdds
FROM dbo.GrandNational
```

Comment: Hmm, when I include that to my select statement it returns: `Column 'dbo.NewRaceResult.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` The query still runs if I remove it - could this be formatting?

Comment: @Dallas There is no column `ID` in my code. What code are you executing? You have a View and my query is based on that View.

Comment: I included it as part of my View which threw out the error - It's working now as I am querying the View directly